# Taking the ball after scoring penalty

Tags: football, scoring, goalkeeper

Why do players intend to take the ball with them after they have scored a goal? In addition to this, the opponent players(especially goalkeepers) don't intend to give away the ball. What could be the reason behind that? Answer from both scorer's and goalkeepers point of view would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If the scoring team is still behind (say, the score was 2-0 but after the goal it's 2-1), the scoring team wants to continue the game as soon as possible, in order to score another goal. On the other hand, the goalkeeper's team will benefit from a delay, so they tend to keep the ball as well.

Other than that, I've seen some instances where the ball becomes part of the small celebration the scoring team holds (especially late in the game when the goal is likely to be decisive). Whether this happens varies from team to team and is just one of the traditional habits of any sport, without a special meaning.